# How to read a text file from the last line to the first

Tags: java, android

I need this to run in reverse so that the lines appear in the reverse order of this.  Is there a quick way to flip a TextView or something like that?  Thanks for any help.

```
try {
// Create a URL for the desired page
URL url = new URL("text.txt");

// Read all the text returned by the server
BufferedReader MyBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;
line = MyBr.readLine();
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = MyBr.readLine()) != null) {
total.append(line + "\r\n");}

textview1.setText(total);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/wonderfull.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
MyBr.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are changing the UI in your code, this must be run on the UI thread. Of course you know that doing I/O like this on the UI thread is a no-no and can easily create ANRs. So we'll just assume this is pseudo-code. Your best bet is to reverse things as you read the stream. You could [insert at the front of the StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) for example.

Comment: I'm a total noob.  No idea what the UI thread is and I'm not afraid of ANRs yet, BUT your advice got me past my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: The code in your Activity (and any code it calls) is executed on the main/UI thread of your application. If you do something that takes a long time (> 100ms) then your application will seem pause and freeze up to the user. If they try to scroll or tap buttons, the application will not respond. Users don't like that. If you tie up the UI thread for more than 5 seconds, the Android OS will present the user with a dialog saying "Foo Application is Not Responding". That's an ANR. It will give the user the option to terminate your application.

Comment: You don't want that to happen. So spawn a new thread to do long tasks like reading a file from the network. You can use a good 'ol java.lang.Thread or you can use Android goodness like android.os.AsyncTask. Read up on those classes from the SDK docs.

Also if my answer helped, then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also directly insert into the Editable:

```
Editable e = textview1.getEditableText();
while ((line = MyBr.readLine()) != null) {
    e.insert(0, line + "\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this class: java.io.RandomAccessFile, http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file into an array or array list and then use a for loop to print it from the last index to the first.